# mysqldb db host is not being accepted?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I do :

```
db=_mysql.connect(host="83.101.*.*",port=****,passwd="mypassword",user="myuser",db="myDB")
```

and I get this error message :

```
OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'myuser'@'91.176.*.*' (using password: YES)")
```

the 91.176.*.* is my home IP the 83.101.*.* is my server I am trying to reach. I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong :/.

Comment: is the user name and password correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have SSH to your server, from the server shell login as root in mysql, and set host to '%' in the mysql.users table for the myuser record.
If this is a paid hosting / server, ask your support to enable remote login.

Comment: fixed it, the password for remote connections wasnt set

Answer (score 0):

That combination of username and host does not have that password. Either the username does not exist, the username is not allowed to connect from that host, or the password is incorrect.

Comment: I just pasted the password and user right from my code in cli and it worked :/

Comment: And how exactly does that refute what I wrote?